# using directive error for file/directory that is in that location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to build a web site project in Visual Studio 2015.

I'm getting errors (many, using directives, this is just one example) saying: "The type or namespace name 'DbTier' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)" when DbTier is clearly where the using directive says it is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've looked at the other Stack Overflow pages similar to my problem but changing Property Pages > Build > Target Framework to '.NET Framework 4' does not work.

Comment: folder structure doesn't show in which namespace the type is declared.

Comment: Post the contents of `DbTier` class, including the namespace

Comment: You need to post the contents as text, images of code are not allowed.  Besides, your last two images are identical

Comment: Added DbTier screen shot.

Comment: Can you make the namespace match the file location?

Comment: Are you sure `DbTier` compiled? If it contains certain types of errors, it won't, and the `DbTier` symbol will remain undefined. Sift through all your compilation errors and see if you can find one that would prevent it from compiling.

Comment: There's no errors anywhere in the DbTier file.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but all of the .cs files not recognizing a using directive--that is where it says it is--are in the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since DbTier is in the Users folder, try to add

```
using depaulOAR.Classes.Users;
```

Let me know how that turns out.

Comment: That didn't work. When I go to type depaulOAR.Classes. intellisense doesn't suggest Users at all.

Comment: Try to make the namespace match the file location. Since your file is in the Users forlder. Make your namespace depaulOAR.Classes.Users;

Comment: That didn't work either. It does not seem to recognize the Users directory even though it's there.